# How can I query all DNS entries known by my DNS server?

Tags: domain-name-system

My office relies on a lot of custom DNS entries to store useful information, but the site listing isn't well documented.

I'd like to search the network and see what's available that I may not know about. I know that all of our custom entries have a specific .pvt TLD, so I can filter for what I'm looking for, but I don't know how to get a raw dump from my DNS server.

I am not a network administrator so I don't actually have access to the DNS server. I'd like to know if there is some what that I can query the server and basically ask "what DNS records do you know?"

I'm not sure if this is a thing that exists or not.

Comment: Ask someone who does have access.

Comment: take a look at the zone files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be able to get a complete dump of a zone with a zone transfer:

```
dig axfr example.com
```

However, this is usually heavily restricted. If it's not working and you need this data, talk to someone who can help you.